# How to get this value?

Tags: vb.net

Ive been trying to get this value from wb forever now.. And can't do it.
What I am trying to get is "388399"
However "ember557" changes constantly to "ember'random number'" and the class is not unique.

```html
<div id="ember557" class="ember-view">388399</div>
```

Comment: Reference it as the nth child of something with a fixed ID or loop `GetElementsByTagName("div")`, and examine `class/id`.

Comment: What is `wb`? I'm missing the non-working code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "web browser" I suspect

Comment: how you are trying to get this? where is your VB.Net code? you question is not clear at all

Comment: So the ID is changing and the class not unique. Without code, how would you find this control at all?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to get it with the CLASS instead of the ID
you can call GetElementByTagName and then iterate through this to find the element of the relevant class

And if that doesnt work then you could also try to use regex to get the string you want. Then replace the unwanted characters.

```
Dim myString As String = "your html string here"
Dim regex = New Regex("<div id=""ember[0-9]*"" class=""ember-view"">[0-9]*</div>")
Dim match = regex.Match(myString)
If match.Success Then
   'replace the unwanted characters.
End If
```